# Fail2Ban Postfix sometimes banning domain names instead of IP addresses in iptables

Tags: iptables, postfix, fail2ban

I'm running an Ubuntu server with Postfix serving as a mail relay. To prevent brute force attacks, I installed Fail2Ban and configured it to look at `/var/log/mail.log` to ban IPs accordingly. I'm using the default Postfix filter `[FAIL2BAN_FOLDER]/filter.d/postfix.conf` that comes with Fail2Ban, configured to the strictest detection mode so that it captures SASL login failures too.

The regex in `postfix.conf` that catches failed Postfix logins is as follows:

```
^[^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: SASL ((?i)LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed:(?! Connection lost to authentication server
```

It perfectly captures all failed logins to the mail relay, and using `fail2ban-client status postfix` will show me all the IPs that have been banned for brute forcing. However, when I check `iptables --list`, I get some entries that do not ban IP addresses, but domain names instead. Below are some examples:

```
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  vm5403.hv8.ru        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  179.185.35.150.static.gvt.net.br  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I don't use `iptables` independently, but only through Fail2Ban. Is this something I should be concerned about? What I can do to rectify it if it happens to be an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that this is something that fail2ban actually does, rather I suspect that you are being confused by `iptables --list` looking up the names for presentation purposes.

Add `-n` to your `iptables --list` command to disable this.

From the `iptables` manual (emphasis added):

> -L, --list [chain]
>                 List  all rules in the selected chain.  If no chain is selected,
>                 all chains are listed. Like every  other  iptables  command,  it
>                 applies  to  the specified table (filter is the default), so NAT
>                 rules get listed by
>                  iptables -t nat -n -L
>                 **Please note that it is often used with the -n option,  in  order
>                 to  avoid  long reverse DNS lookups.**  It is legal to specify the
>                 -Z (zero) option as well, in which case  the  chain(s)  will  be
>                 atomically  listed  and zeroed.  The exact output is affected by
>                 the other arguments given. The exact rules are suppressed  until
>                 you use
>                  iptables -L -v
>                 or iptables-save(8).

Comment: Thanks! No wonder `iptables --list` was taking so long to execute. It was doing an rDNS. It's a relief to know that my fail2ban is configured right.